# Why does the text in .xaml not display in WPF .NET 4.8

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, .net-4.8

I am a complete newbie to WPF, but this should not be something that I'm supposed to take too much time into.

Basically, I'd like to display `userName` by binding to the view:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserCellTemplate">
    <Grid Width="190">
        <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding userName}"/>
        <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="123456"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

But somehow, this part does not work at all, even when I tested with random text "123456" to be displayed, but it does not display to the view - without showing any error or warning.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserHeaderTemplate">
    <Grid Width="190">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="User"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This code however seems to work perfectly fine, using the same exact logic.

Here is the full code, I also tested to see if "123456" displays after removing the `Binding` part but still the same. I'd greatly appreciate if anyone can point out my issue and help me fix this, thank you

```
<Window x:Class="ChattingClient.UserListWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChattingClient"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="UserListWindow" Height="400" Width="250" Background="#BCBCBC">
    <Grid Margin="10,10,10,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="UserListView" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="White">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="UserCellTemplate">
                    <Grid Width="190">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Text="{Binding userName}"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Text="123456"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="UserHeaderTemplate">
                    <Grid Width="190">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="User"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.Resources>

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn
                        HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource UserHeaderTemplate}"
                        CellTemplate="{DynamicResource UserCellTemplate}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,5">
            <Button x:Name="Chatting_btn" Click="Chatting_btn_Click"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: _I am a complete newbie to WPF, but this should not be something that im supposed to take too much time into_: Seems like you haven't invested enough time into understanding binding. I'd say that proper binding is the most difficult part to understand when learning WPF. Therefore, one needs to invest a lot of time studying it.

Comment: 1. Where and how did you set the ItemsSource of the list view? 2. You define the DataTemplate "UserCellTemplate" but seem to not use it anywhere.